# A simple question about syntax: how to shorten OwnValues@...OwnValues@

Tags: evaluation, compile, downvalues

Consider the following function:

```
func[a_, b_, c_, d_, x_] = (a + b + c + d)*x;
aval = 1;
bval = 2;
ccval = 3;
dval = 4;
Hold@Compile[{x, _Real}, func[aval, bval, ccval, dval, x], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
   OwnValues@aval/.OwnValues@bval/.OwnValues@ccval/.OwnValues@dval /.DownValues@func // ReleaseHold
```

The code `OwnValues@...OwnValues@..` is very long. Is it possible to shorten it so `OwnValues@` would be used only once?

For `DownValues`, I do not experience such problems:

```
rule = Flatten[
   DownValues /@ {func}];
```

And then

```
Hold@Compile[{x, _Real}, func[aval, bval, ccval, dval, x], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]/.OwnValues@aval/.OwnValues@bval/.OwnValues@ccval/.OwnValues@dval//.rule// ReleaseHold
```

The same construction as in `rule` does not work for `OwnValues`:

```
rule = Flatten[OwnValues /@ {aval, bval, ccval, dval}];
```

> OwnValues::sym: Argument 1 at position 1 is expected to be a symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would this be acceptable solution?

```
Compile[...] /. Flatten[OwnValues /@ (Unevaluated@{aval, bval, ccval, dval})]
```

Obviosuly, you can make an auxilliary function

```
SetAttributes[injectDefs, HoldAll];
injectDefs[symbs_] := Flatten[OwnValues /@ (Unevaluated@symbs)]

Compile[...] /. injectDefs[{aval, bval, ccval, dval}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Define

```
 repl={{name, value}.,..}.
```

Then you always can use

```
 expr/.Rule@@@repl 

 expr/.RuleDelayed@@@repl

 f@@Subtract@@@repl
 
 And@@Equal@@@repl
```

and this one ends it use

```
  Set@@@repl
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I do not see how to apply these points directly to my question.

Answer (score 2):

`OwnValues` works with string names:

```
rule = Flatten[OwnValues /@ {"aval", "bval", "ccval", "dval"}];
```

---

Alternative approach independent of number of symbols and their names:

```
Hold@Compile[{x, _Real}, func[aval, bval, ccval, dval, x], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] //
 # //. Flatten@
    Cases[#, 
     s_Symbol?(Function[s, 
         Context[Unevaluated@s] === "Global`" && 
          ValueQ[s, Method -> "SymbolDefinitionsPresent"], HoldAll]) :>
       Join[OwnValues[s], DownValues[s]], Infinity, Heads -> True] &
```

Comment: Thanks! A very elegant solution. Just a stupid question: is it okay to have simultaneously `DownValues@func` and `OwnValues@func`, as well as those for `aval` etc?

Comment: Also, in `Mathematica 12.1`, it says: `ValueQ::argx: ValueQ called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected.`. Does it mean that it is inconsistent with older versions of Mathematica?

Comment: Finally, why in `ValueQ` the option is `SymbolDefinitionsPresent` but no `OwnValuesPresent`?

Comment: @JohnTaylor `Join[OwnValues[s], DownValues[s]]` should be ok. If there are `OwnValues`, they will be applied first, which is what happens normally.  If there are no values, `OwnValues[s]` returns `{}`, so all the rules you get are `DownValues[s]`. -- I'm using 13.2. I guess they hadn't added the options to `ValueQ` in 12.1. I don't see a real problem with just omitting it: If no values, then `Join[OwnValues[s], DownValues[s]]` returns `{}`. No values for a global symbol in `Compile` is usually a mistake anyway. -- You'll have to ask WRI why `ValueQ` has the options it does. I don't know.

Comment: Thanks! Excuse me for the annoying questions: in Mathematica 13.2, if not using any option for `ValueQ` would return errors? I am asking because I do not have this version yet.

Comment: @JohnTaylor In 13.2 `ValuesQ[func]` returns `False` and `ValueQ[func, Method -> "SymbolDefinitionsPresent"]` returns `True`.  (Actually, going back to one of your earlier questions, the default `ValueQ[s]` is probably the same as what you meant by "`OwnValuesPresent`".  What's missing is `DownValuesPresentOnly`. As well as other logical combinations of `*Values`, I suppose.)

Comment: I have tested some evaluation of the compiled code in my actual notebook with the standard `DownValues@...DownValues@...OwnValues@...` and with your solution. I mean not the compilation time, but the actual evaluation (just to avoid ambiguity in my formulation). In the second case, the evaluation is longer (many times longer for the particular example). How do you think, what may be a generic reason for this? A lot of extra symbols defined within the current session?

Comment: It actually looks like it may have missed some functions to be down-valued maybe (this is Mathematica 12.1, where I removed `Method -> "SymbolDefinitionsPresent"` from `ValueQ`)...

Comment: @JohnTaylor The slowness is probably the duplicate rules. Try `DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Cases[#...`. -- I forget how the old `ValueQ` works. Using `Function[s, Context[Unevaluated@s] === "Global`", HoldAll]` with no `ValueQ` should work and be faster. (I didn't think about the fact that your actual `Compile` is very large in my initial answer.)